# What does ? stand for in PHP (after href operator)?

Tags: php, operator-keyword

I have the following problem:

I use a template page for a specific application, and for the login through "steam" there is a button. The button refers to a php file, and in the php file you can find the following line of code:

```
 <a href="?login"><div id="sign-in-steam" style="margin-left: 74px;color: black;">
```

What does the "?login" exactly mean, I know it stands for a file but I cant find a file named like that, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Looks like a link to a query parameter to me. Not a PHP thing.

Comment: No, it's probably not "a file".  Look here for an example of HTTP "GET" syntax: [HTTP Request Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: You could have Google'd your title, and/or ***"what does ? in a url do in php?".***

Answer (score 3):

The part behind the question mark in any URL is the [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) as per [RFC 3986 section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) and hence is not a PHP functionality (even though PHP can read it, see [PHP $_SERVER superglobal docs](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php), especially `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`).

Answer (score 1):

The hyper reference

```
?login
```

refers to the **web-apps main page**, which gets called using the parameter `login` a a **GET parameter**.

Quite likely, this would call the same script equivalently:

```
index.php?login
```